# PL/SQL- Count number of lines in a txt file and append zeros

Tags: plsql

I have a stored procedure that outputs a text file.

I want to count the number of lines in the text file and need to append zeros before that number, so that the file name is of fixed length.

If the file has 10 lines, I have to display as `000000000010`; if the lines are 120, then `000000000120`.

Comment: So what is your specific problem? Post your code and point the place where you are stuck.

Comment: To create a string with 12 digits: LPAD(number_of_lines,12,'0')

Answer (score 0):

Pablomatico solution is right:

1. count number of lines in your file

   ... for this, there are multiple possibilities, since we know not how you store your file (BLOB or file system?). The best to do would be to count end of lines at the time you output them to the file.
2. output with leading zeros

   `LPAD(number_of_lines,12,'0')`